# how to make background images appeared on pug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

Background images does not appeared on pug? Upon inspection on, it give me this error.
Is this relatable?

2
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/materialize.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

This are my source code for my background image in pug.

```html
/* pictures animation  */

  .picturesz {
  
  background-image:
  url(imagez/tp9.jpg);
  animation: snow 40s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes snow {
  0% {
  background-position: 150px 150px, 150px 150px, 150px 150px;
  }
  
  80% {
  background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px
  }
  
  }
```

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are importing an stylesheet? i mean, if you visit http://localhost:3000/css/materialize.min.css in your web browser and is the stylesheet what is served by node, the thing is that the error provided says you are trying to import an text/html mime type, maybe your nodejs server is not serving your static files the way is intended to be.

Comment: Hello, first of all, just open http://localhost:3000/css/materialize.min.css in your browser and make sure is an stylesheet and not another page served by your server, if you open that in your browser and what you see is somthing like this `/*!
 * Materialize v1.0.0 (http://materializecss.com)
 * Copyright 2014-2017 Materialize
 * MIT License` then you are seen the actually css, if you see something different, you have a problem serving the static files and it is not a pug error maybe i need to see more about your project so i can help you.